# How to get the navigation element to have horizontal lines after each nav element in css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am looking to have a navigation element that looks like this:

```
nav | nav | nav | nav
```

But I am unsure how to get the horizontal lines in place with proper spacing, what I currently have, in sass is:

```
#brusters-footer-nav {
  text-align: center;

  ul {
    list-style: none;

    li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the next steps to get the navigation the way I want it?

Comment: Why was this question down voted, I provided a clear question with examples of what I wanted and my work to show where I was stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `border` to your `li` tags

```
#brusters-footer-nav {
  text-align: center;
}

  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      padding: 0 5px; 
    }

    li:last-child{
        border-right: none;
    }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a85qqt9n/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), to select and add a left border to adjacent `li` elements.

In other words, this *won't* add the border to the first `li`.

```
li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

You could also use the [`:not` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
</ul>
```